# Cookie notice keeps opening even after users have click their preferences and closed the box

Tags: javascript, cookies, google-analytics, session-cookies, google-tag-manager

We have been given a Google Tag code by our client's IT team. It generates a standard Cookie notice for users to select and accept preferences. However, even after choosing a preference and closing the box, the notice still re-appears after the page reloads or we navigate to another page. In addition to this, it seemingly does not remember the previous preference.

I'm guessing there is something obvious we're missing here. Any help appreciated.

Site:
https://heroesbibletrivia.org

Google Tag recieved from IT team:

Place this code as high in the  as possible:

```
<!-- Google Tag Manager -->
<script>(function(w,d,s,l,i){w[l]=w[l]||[];w[l].push({'gtm.start':
new Date().getTime(),event:'gtm.js'});var f=d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0],
j=d.createElement(s),dl=l!='dataLayer'?'&l='+l:'';j.async=true;j.src=
'https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtm.js?id='+i+dl;f.parentNode.insertBefore(j,f);
})(window,document,'script','dataLayer','GTM-K3VZ5MK');</script>
<!-- End Google Tag Manager —>
```

And place this right after the opening  tag:

```
And place this right after the opening <body> tag: 
<!-- Google Tag Manager (noscript) -->
<noscript><iframe src="https://www.googletagmanager.com/ns.html?id=GTM-K3VZ5MK"
height="0" width="0" style="display:none;visibility:hidden"></iframe></noscript>
<!-- End Google Tag Manager (noscript) —>
```

Comment: This is the generic Google Tag Manager Snippet. While maybe your cookie notice is deployed via Google Tag Manager, GTM itself has nothing to do with it. You need to look into the GTM interface to see what is configured there.

Comment: Thanks Eike. I guess my concern was that it was something to do with us incorrectly applying the code to the HTML markup. But your comment suggests its an issue with the GTM setup. I'll go back to the client's IT team and ask them to look into it.

Comment: You also set tracking cookies before the user have accepted cookies or changed their settings, which kind of defeats the purpose of having the cookie notice.